# Convert Univariate Contingecy Table to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, contingency

I have a univariate contingency table that I would like to convert to a data frame.

```
>t <- table(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4))
>t

1 2 3 4 
4 4 4 4
```

But converting t to a data frame yields something I dont need:

```
>data.frame(t)
  Var1 Freq
1    1    4
2    2    4
3    3    4
4    4    4
```

I would like a data frame that looks exactly like the table t, with 4 columns named 1, 2, 3 and 4 (or X1, X2, X3, X4), and one row.  Any help I can find, using things like as.data.frame.matrix() return errors for me, I think because my data is univariate and not multivariate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.data.frame.list()`

```
tbl <- table(rep(1:4, 4))

as.data.frame.list(tbl)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  4  4  4  4
```

Or to use the original names, add `optional = TRUE`

```
as.data.frame.list(tbl, optional = TRUE)
#   1 2 3 4
# 1 4 4 4 4
```